# How to install Joomla Flash Templates Via Admin?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-template

I Have tried Installing Joomla Flash Templates into my localhost by using admin interface.
But Everytime I get an error as "Template cannot be uploaded on server" due to some error.

Please help me what could be the reason behind this.
I am using Joomla 1.5

Comment: good error, are more details available?

Answer (score 0):

Cool ! use the manual way . I think you need to upload a site template

copy/FTP the files into

> joomla_home_folder/templates/yourtheme\

if you need to automate it set the FTP settings in the  file

> configuration.php